# ASP.NET 4.6 - VS 2015 - Add service reference to a MVC project

Tags: asp.net-mvc, vb.net

In VS 2013 if I add a service reference to the project it creates the default 'ServiceReference1' and a host of configuration files underneath.

I have just created a new MVC project and as usual created a service reference and pointed it to the correct WCF server. It creates 'ServiceReference1' but no configuration files.

Usually it can be imported into the page with

```
Imports ProjectName.ServiceReference1
```

but that is not available...

What has changed?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I uncheck 'Reuse types in referenced assemblies' it works, but this has never been an issue in prior versions...